# Glassfish 2.0 - per node JVM config

Tags: cluster, glassfish, java

I have a Glassfish (2.0) cluster with two nodes. I want to pass some extra JVM settings to a single node only. Is this configurable? At least from the console I see, this selective configuration is only for system properties, but not for the JVM settings.